# Removing one subview from superview in swift somehow makes another view invisible

Tags: swift

Can someone help me understand why removing a subview from superview somehow makes another subview in the superview disappear visually? Code is shown below:

```
private func setupSubviews() {
        ...
        ...
        self.view.addSubview(self.feedView) feedView   
        self.view.addSubview(self.bannerView)
    }
```

```
private func setupConstraints() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
        self.feedView.backgroundColor = .white
        self.feedView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
        self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        self.bannerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        constrain(self.feedView, self.view, self.bannerView) { feedView, container, banner in
            feedView.left == container.left
            feedView.right == container.right
            feedView.bottom == banner.top
            banner.left == container.left
            banner.right == container.right

        }

        for view in self.view.subviews {
            print("View: ", view)
            //self.feedView.removeFromSuperview()
            if view is DFPBannerView {
                print(self.bannerView.superview)
                self.bannerView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }

        for view in self.view.subviews {
            print("&&&***", view) //show the feedViews is still here
            print(view.isHidden) //shows false
        }
```

In the `setupSubviews`, I've added to subviews, `feeView` and `bannerView`. I need to remove the `bannerView` from the superview but for whatever reason when `self.bannerView.removeFromSuperview()` runs, the feedView also disappear visually. It's actually still in the `self.views.subviews` as I tried to see if it's still there but for some reason, nothing shows up other than just the white background.

If however I remove the `feedView` instead, the `bannerView` still shows up visually.

I naively thought perhaps somehow the feedView's `isHidden` property got set to true so I tried `self.feedView.isHidden = false`, but that didn't do anything.

So my question is what am I missing?

Comment: `feedView.bottom == banner.top`.

Comment: Can you explain it a bit in detail? I rarely do iOS stuff. Is it because if the ```bannerView``` disappears than ```feedView```'s bottom contraint no longer has anything to reference by?

Comment: That's my suspicion. Try setting the `top` constraint on `feedView` so it knows where to be even if `bannerView` is removed.

Comment: Hold on, you were right

Comment: So does that mean I need to somehow update the constraints when I remove the ```bannerView```?

Comment: yep, otherwise the autolayout won't be able to correctly calculate the size and position of your views. In your example it might be that constraint between the feedview and the banner is removed after you remove the banner from its superview, so you need to constrain feedView.bottom to some another anchor in order to determine its height and/or bottom side position